# Combined flair is double escaping some Turkish characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, combined-flair, html-entities

This isn't a serious problem but in Stack Exchange flair tooltips, there is some problem with rendering Turkish characters; they are being double escaped when converted to HTML entities. The following characters have that issue -

<kbd>ç</kbd>, <kbd>ğ</kbd>, <kbd>ı</kbd>, <kbd>ö</kbd>, <kbd>ş</kbd>, <kbd>ü</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, combined flair tooltip looks broken because img title attribute uses `&amp;` instead of ampersand that works fine in ordinary flair.

Bug *was* easy to see at your flair page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul/flair (as reproduced at screen shot below; note it has been recently fixed).

When hovering over your combined flair tooltip shows `&#246;` instead of `ö` (see screen shot below, tested with Firefox and IE). This page also shows how to do it right - ordinary flair tooltip, with plain ampersands in title looks OK.

- snippet of combined flair code:
  `title="profile for Soner G&amp;#246;n&amp;#252;l on Stack Exchange..."`
- for the reference - snippet of ordinary flair code:
  `title="profile for Soner G&#246;n&#252;l at Stack Overflow..."`

Note that `alt` attribute in combined flair code appears to have the same issue.

---

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zstzs.png]

---

A workaround for this bug is to manually replace `&amp;` when copying combined flair code.

- If corrected that way, tooltip looks OK:

  [image: profile for Soner Gönül on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]